# Installed Self-Grounding 3 prong in place of 2 prong

Tags: receptacle

I had a 2 prong plug in place where I needed a 3 prong. (no heavy loads, just TV and such) I read about replacing this with a 3 prong and found out the following:

1. If the hot end to the box screw registers a voltage, then the metal box in the wall is grounded.
2. I should use a GFCI outlet if possible in the box.

When I opened the outlet I realized that the box is too small for the GFCI outlet. Instead, I had a self-grounding 3 prong outlet.

I installed the self-grounding outlet, and tested with a circuit tester. The circuit tester lights up normal. However, my contact-less tester beeps on each hole. I also measure the following voltages:

- Hot to Neutral - 120V
- Neutral to Ground - 0V
- Hot to Ground - 120V

Is this normal for a self-grounding outlet?

Comment: What is the resistance ~~line~~ ground to neutral?

Comment: do you mean hot to neutral? Can I measure this with the power on?

Comment: Sorry; ground to neutral. Was thinking of other things.

Comment: I will check now, I can do this with the power still on right?

Comment: Yes, power on is fine.

Comment: So I have a regular multimeter so the measurement is a bit touchy. Its Neutral to Ground is infinity dead one, but I can wiggle it to 0 Ohms.

Comment: I checked a few more outlets around the house and this is consistent. Happens on all of them.

Comment: 0 ohms is the same as what happens when you touch the leads to each other? If so, you're fine. That outlet is properly grounded.

Comment: Right, so you're saying that the ground and neutral should be shorted? (yes, 0 Ohms is what happens when i touch the leads) I also tested it using continuity and I get a beep, a bit broken but I get a beep.

Comment: If the netural and ground and shorted, then it makes sense to me that I'm reading 120 V hot to neutral and then 120V hot to ground

Comment: Do you have metal boxes? Conduit or non metallic cable (aka Romex)? Do you have bare metal ground wires in the back of the box and attached to the metal box?

Comment: I have metal boxes, I can't see the conduit behind it. There is no metal ground wire in the box. There are two screws on the back side of the box, but I can't confirm that they are attached to ground. I should also note that I haven't see metal cable sheaths. Everything coming out of the box looks like pvc cover.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Oh boy, I'd love to and I should have taken a picture, but its so tight, and the cables are so short I barely got the plug back on.  Sorry, but I dont think I can.

Comment: Just to make clear, when you touch two points with the leads of a multimeter in voltage mode, you are not shorting the two points because a voltmeter is a high resistance. If you would touch two points in current mode you would be shorting them because the resistance of a current meter is close to zero. If you would (wrongly!) touch the hot and neutral or ground with the meter is a current or resistance mode you will at the least blow a fuse in the meter or trip a breaker in the meter. Don't ever do this intentionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have metal boxes? The findings of 120 V hot to ground, 120 V hot to neutral, and low resistance neutral to ground are consistent with separate ground and neutral paths to the panel and that is almost certainly what you have.

The ground and neutral are supposed to be connected in the panel and only in the panel. If that is what you have, the resistance you measure between neutral and ground at a receptacle is the lengths of neutral and ground wire back to the panel where they are connected.

**EDIT**

You need to determine that there is a separate ground path (metal conduit or a ground wire) all the way to the panel. The other possibility consistent (I think) with your measurement results is that someone has connected the grounds of the each receptacle to the neutral in each box. I think this is called a "bootleg ground" and it is not according to code and not safe. I think you would see evidence of this inside the boxes.

Time for you to take pictures of the inside of one or more boxes and attach the picture to your question. Also time for one of the experts to comment.

**EDIT2**

[Bootleg ground wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootleg_ground). You could take off one or more faceplates on receptacles. You could take off the "dead front" on your panel and see if you have ground wires there. Of course, you could be grounded via conduit.

Comment: This makes sense Jim. What baffles me is that other outlets are not measuring 120V hot to ground. And yes, I have metal boxes - at least its metal on this outlet. I havent looked at others yet.

Comment: What are you getting for hot to ground at these other outlets? Do these other outlets have grounded receptacles? When was this house built? Was it in the time that receptacles were not grounded, i.e., two slots neutral and hot?

Comment: Ok, checked again. Looks like If I wiggle my probe I do get hot to ground 120V. The house was built 1930 which I'm pretty sure is pre mandatory 3 prong.

Comment: You need to determine that there is a separate ground path (metal conduit or a ground wire) all the way to the panel. The other possibility for your measurement results is that someone has connected the grounds of the each receptacle to the neutral in each box. I think this is called a "bootleg ground" and it is not according to code and not safe. I think you would see evidence of this inside the boxes.